# How to revert a file in Perforce?

Tags: perforce

In Perforce, how do I revert changes I have made a file?

```
$ p4 status
UI\FormMain.cs - reconcile to edit //UI/FormMain.cs#73

$ p4 revert UI/FormMain.cs
UI/FormMain.cs - file(s) not opened on this client.
```

---

In Git I do this with the command `git checkout` or `git restore`.

```
$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   Form.cs
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

$ git checkout Form.cs

$ git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Comment: The usual Perforce workflow is to explicitly open files for edit *first* via `p4 edit` before touching the files (otherwise the server won't know and won't do anything when you try `p4 revert`).  If you follow that practice, things will go more smoothly.

Comment: Are people actually still using Perforce?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the file isn't opened, yet you have made changes to it locally, use

```
p4 sync -f UI/FormMain.cs
```

to tell Perforce to forcibly (-f) sync the copy of FormMain.cs that you have on your machine with the version from the server.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `p4 revert UI/FormMain.cs` you should call `p4 revert //UI/FormMain.cs` since that's the absolute path in depot notation.
The file with out the leading `//` marks a file relative to your current location in the client workspace.

Comment: This doesn't work, it gives me the same 'file(s) not opened on this client.' error.

Comment: what does "p4 opened" tell you?

Comment: `p4 revert <file>` works only for files opened for edit with `p4 edit <file>` or via checkout operation in P4V application